Unable to display abstract and bibliography using specialized class
With option sagev I'm able to get the shown pdf, but with option sageapa, I get the shown error. In each there is no abstract (is it meant to?)
tex:
%\documentclass[sagev]{sagej}
\documentclass[sageapa]{sagej}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% -----
\begin{document}

\runninghead{Anon}
\title{\lipsum[1][1]}
\author{Anon}
\corrauth{Anon}
\email{Anon}
  \begin{abstract}\lipsum[2]
  \end{abstract}
\keywords{\lipsum[3][1]}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\lipsum[5]\cite{nosek-2020-replic}\endnote{\lipsum[6][1]}

\section{Main}

\lipsum[7]

\theendnotes

%\bibliographystyle{SageV}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{nosek-2020-replic}
Nosek BA and Errington TM.
\newblock What is replication?
\newblock \emph{PLOS Biology} 2020; 18(3): 1--8.
\newblock \doi{10.1371/journal.pbio.3000691}.

\end{thebibliography}

%\bibliography{sagej-dummy-a.bib}

\end{document}

console:
$ ls *age* | grep -E 'bst|cls'
sagej.cls
SageV.bst
$ ls sagej-dummy-a.*
sagej-dummy-a.bib  sagej-dummy-a.bib~  sagej-dummy-a.tex  sagej-dummy-a.tex~
$ pdflatex sagej-dummy-a.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sagej-dummy-a.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(./sagej.cls
[truncated]
Document Class: sagej 2017/01/17 v1.20\ sagej.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty)
[truncated]
No file sagej-dummy-a.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `nosek-2020-replic' on page 1 undefined on input line 2
2.

(./sagej-dummy-a.ent)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr 
                     
l.33 \bibitem{nosek-2020-replic}
                                
? 

log
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.4.13)  2 NOV 2024 23:49
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**sagej-dummy-a.tex
(./sagej-dummy-a.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(./sagej.cls
Document Class: sagej 2017/01/17 v1.20\ sagej.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
Package: rotating 2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
\c@r@tfl@t=\count196
\rotFPtop=\skip50
\rotFPbot=\skip51
\rot@float@box=\box51
\rot@mess@toks=\toks18
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count197
\calc@Bcount=\count198
\calc@Adimen=\dimen143
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen144
\calc@Askip=\skip52
\calc@Bskip=\skip53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count199
\calc@Cskip=\skip54
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2023/07/27 v1.04 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
Package textcase Info: Defining Legacy names on input line 20.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen145
\lightrulewidth=\dimen146
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen147
\belowrulesep=\dimen148
\belowbottomsep=\dimen149
\aboverulesep=\dimen150
\abovetopsep=\dimen151
\cmidrulesep=\dimen152
\cmidrulekern=\dimen153
\defaultaddspace=\dimen154
\@cmidla=\count266
\@cmidlb=\count267
\@aboverulesep=\dimen155
\@belowrulesep=\dimen156
\@thisruleclass=\count268
\@lastruleclass=\count269
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen157
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2022/01/06 v1.3d Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 149.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/endnotes/endnotes.sty
Package: endnotes 2020-01-02 endnotes package
\c@endnote=\count270
\endnotesep=\dimen158
\@enotes=\write3
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\symAMSa=\mathgroup5
\symAMSb=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen159
)
\pmbraise@=\dimen160
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip55

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count271
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count272
\leftroot@=\count273
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count274
\DOTSCASE@=\count275
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen161
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count276
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count277
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count278
\dspbrk@lvl=\count279
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count280
\column@=\count281
\maxfields@=\count282
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen162
\alignsep@=\dimen163
\tagshift@=\dimen164
\tagwidth@=\dimen165
\totwidth@=\dimen166
\lineht@=\dimen167
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip56
\multlinetaggap=\skip57
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks25
\thm@bodyfont=\toks26
\thm@headfont=\toks27
\thm@notefont=\toks28
\thm@headpunct=\toks29
\thm@preskip=\skip58
\thm@postskip=\skip59
\thm@headsep=\skip60
\dth@everypar=\toks30
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tracefnt.sty
Package: tracefnt 2020/12/22 v3.0n Standard LaTeX package (font tracing)
\tracingfonts=\count283
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 107.
Applying: [2021/06/01] Add hook to \selectfont  on input line 142.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Add hook to \selectfont  on input line 145.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count284
\Gm@cntv=\count285
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count286
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen168
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen169
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen170
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen171
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen172
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen173
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen174
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen175
\Gm@dimlist=\toks31
)
\absbox=\box54
\@bls=\dimen176

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2023/08/05 v3.6o Customizing captions (AR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2023/07/31 v2.4d caption3 kernel (AR)
\caption@tempdima=\dimen177
\captionmargin=\dimen178
\caption@leftmargin=\dimen179
\caption@rightmargin=\dimen180
\caption@width=\dimen181
\caption@indent=\dimen182
\caption@parindent=\dimen183
\caption@hangindent=\dimen184
Package caption Info: Standard document class detected.
)
\c@caption@flags=\count287
\c@continuedfloat=\count288
Package caption Info: rotating package is loaded.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mslapa/mslapa.sty
\bibhang=\skip61
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count289
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
))
Package: l3keys2e 2024-03-14 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: lipsum 2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\g__lipsum_par_int=\count290
\l__lipsum_a_int=\count291
\l__lipsum_b_int=\count292
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
No file sagej-dummy-a.aux.
\openout1 = `sagej-dummy-a.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count293
\scratchdimen=\dimen185
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count294
\nofMParguments=\count295
\everyMPshowfont=\toks32
\MPscratchCnt=\count296
\MPscratchDim=\dimen186
\MPnumerator=\count297
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count298
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks33
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 1:1
* vratio: 1:1
* modes: twoside asymmetric 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(45.52441pt, 352.81416pt, 45.52441pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(69.70924pt, 526.37598pt, 69.70926pt)
* \paperwidth=443.86299pt
* \paperheight=665.79448pt
* \textwidth=352.81416pt
* \textheight=526.37598pt
* \oddsidemargin=-26.74557pt
* \evensidemargin=-26.74557pt
* \topmargin=-35.56075pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=21.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=12.0pt
* \skip\footins=20.0pt plus 8.0pt
* 

bib
@article{nosek-2020-replic,
    doi = {10.1371/journal.pbio.3000691},
    author = {Nosek, Brian A. and Errington, Timothy M.},
    journal = {PLOS Biology},
    publisher = {Public Library of Science},
    title = {What is replication?},
    year = {2020},
    month = {03},
    volume = {18},
    url = {https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC7100931/},
    pages = {1-8},
    number = {3},
  language = {english}}

files:
LaTeX FAQ for sagej:

How can I generate APA style references using sagej and bibtex? When
adding the “sageapa” option and using BibTeX as normal, everything
should be resolved and the references should be in a good enough APA
form for submission

Sage Sumission Guidelines
Sage LaTeX Template (download)
UPDATE:
"When adding the “sageapa” option and using BibTeX as normal," I tried that too:
tex
\documentclass[sageapa]{sagej}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sagej-dummy-a.bib}

\begin{document}

% As before

% \bibliographystyle{} % disabled
% \begin{thebibliography}  % disabled
% \end{thebibliogaphy} % disabled

\end{document}

console:
$ ls sagej-dummy-a.*
sagej-dummy-a.bib  sagej-dummy-a.bib~  sagej-dummy-a.tex  sagej-dummy-a.tex~

$ pdflatex sagej-dummy-a.tex
[truncated]

! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.899 \newlength{\bibhang}
                          
? 



@cfr I updated the post, not sure it's what you meant.

@cfr the issue is with sageapa, not sagev, for which I have the bst as listed.

if the file is sagev.bst, you want \bibliographystyle{sagev}\bibliography{sagej-dummy-a}. [cleaning up comments you've read as the site doesn't like too many.]

you have those commands commented in your example, but you don't explain why.

@cfr SageV is provided as a basis of comparison; the bibliography compiles fine with it. I've explained why commands are commented in the update, quoting from the listed FAQ: "When adding the “sageapa” option and using BibTeX as normal,".

you aren't using bibtex as normal. you are loading biblatex. if that is not what you tried, update your example. \usepackage[bibencoding=auto]{biblatex} \addbibresource{sagej-dummy-a.bib} is not using bibtex. it is using biblatex. you have to use bibtex.

You need \maketitle or no header information will appear.
For the bibliography, sageapa needs the SageH bibstyle (for author-year citation callouts).
And you need a .bib file to be processed with BibTeX. In the example below I use filecontents* to make the code self-contained, but you can use your own bib file.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{nosek-2020-replic,
  author={Nosek, B. A. and Errington, T. M.},
  title={What is replication?},
  journal={PLOS Biology},
  year=2020,
  volume=18,
  number=3,
  pages={1-8},
  doi={10.1371/journal.pbio.3000691},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[sageapa]{sagej}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\runninghead{Anon}
\title{\lipsum[1][1]}
\author{Anon}
\corrauth{Anon}
\email{Anon}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\keywords{\lipsum[3][1]}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\cite{nosek-2020-replic}\endnote{\lipsum[6][1]}

\section{Main}

\lipsum[7]

\theendnotes

\bibliographystyle{SageH}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}


